# What is the difference between "secuestro", "rapto" and "abducción"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

I have translated abduction into Spanish. I have found three translations. What is the difference between them?

- [secuestro](https://dle.rae.es/secuestro)
- [rapto](https://dle.rae.es/rapto)
- [abducción](https://dle.rae.es/abducci%C3%B3n)

Answer (score 4):

All three secuestro, abducción and rapto are nouns for the action of verbs secuestrar, abducir and raptar, respectively. Now, as to the difference between these:

> *Secuestrar* means to take by force an individual or a means of transport, and can also be used to refer to judicially seize goods that are either illegal or of which the owner is unclear and to determine.
>
> *Abducir* is a verb used mainly to refer to supposed extraterrestrial beings taking someone, and also to attract a person powerfully to oneself, rather than taking a person as in English 'Abduct', which is spelled similarly.
>
> *Raptar* refers only to the forceful or deceitful taking of a person, mainly the case of a man taking a woman.

*Secuestro* is the most commonly used word if you're referring to the taking of a person; *rapto* can also be used, but it's not as common.

Answer (score 2):

**Secuestro** and **Rapto** are synonyms. They implies to retain people against their will. Often with violence (not only physical). Kindnap would be the right translation into english.

**Abducción** is the kind of *kindnap* done by *E.T*. Here the violence is not so explicit.

We also use **abducir** (verb instead of subject) to make reference to a strong and powerful attraction.

Answer (score 2):

Secuestro y rapto normalmente son utilizados como sinónimos, la principal diferencia radica en que normalmente cuando hay un secuestro es solicitada una suma de dinero y en el rapto no siempre es solicitada.

[Secuestrar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XPucYEJ):

> 1. Retener indebidamente a una persona para exigir dinero por su rescate, o para otros fines.

[Raptar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V9ndEOH):

> 1. Secuestrar, retener a alguien en contra de su voluntad, por lo general con el fin de conseguir un rescate.

En el caso de [Abducir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=044zogN) generalmente es empleado para los supuestos secuestros por parte de seres extraterrestres:

> 2. Dicho de una supuesta criatura extraterrestre: Apoderarse de alguien.